# Ejercicio Haskell números felices

Tags: matemáticas, haskell, programación-funcional

Un número feliz es un entero positivo n que verifica la siguiente propiedad: se
reemplaza n por la suma de los cuadrados de sus dígitos y se repite el proceso hasta obtener un 1. Por ejemplo, el 7
es feliz porque:

• 7 → 7^2 = 49

• 49 → 4^2 + 9^2 = 16 + 81 = 97

• 97 → 9^2 + 7^2 = 81 + 49 = 130

• 130 → 1^2 + 3^2 + 0^2 = 1 + 9 + 0 = 10

• 10 → 1^2 + 0^2 = 1 + 0 = 1

Un número que no es feliz es infeliz. En tal caso, el proceso anterior entra en bucle. Por ejemplo, el 4 es infeliz
porque el proceso entra en bucle (aunque el bucle no tiene por qué presentarse en el primer elemento de la secuencia ESTO ÚLTIMO ES IMPORTANTE):

• 4 → 4^2 = 16

• 16 → 1^2 + 6^2 = 1 + 36 = 37

• 37 → 3^2 + 7^2 = 9 + 49 = 58

• 58 → 5^2 + 8^2 = 25 + 64 = 89

• 89 → 8^2 + 9^2 = 64 + 81 = 145

• 145 → 1^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 = 1 + 16 + 25 = 42

• 42 → 4^2 + 2^2 = 16 + 4 = 20

• 20 → 2^2 + 0^2 = 4 + 0 = 4

Define una función `digitosDe :: Integer -> [Integer]` que dado un natural devuelva un lista con sus dígitos:

```
digitosDe :: Integer -> [Integer]
digitosDe x  = reverse (digitosDe' x)
    where digitosDe' x 
            |x < 10 = [x]
            |otherwise = (x `mod` 10) : digitosDe' (x`div`10)
```

Define una función `sumaCuadradosDigitos :: Integer -> Integer` que dado un naturaldevuelva la suma de los cuadrados de sus dígitos:

```
sumaCuadradosDigitos :: Integer -> Integer
sumaCuadradosDigitos x = sum (map (^2) (digitosDe x))
```

Define una función `esFeliz :: Integer -> Bool` que determine si un entero positivo es feliz:

```
esFeliz :: Integer -> Bool
esFeliz x 
    |sumaCuadradosDigitos x == 1 = True
    |otherwise = esFeliz (sumaCuadradosDigitos x)
```

**HE AQUÍ EL PROBLEMA**: no sé cómo parar el bucle en el caso que se detecte que existe

Se me sugiere usar una funcion auxiliar "`esFelizAc`" que use recursión con acumulador y emplear éste para almacenar los números que se van obteniendo en la sucesivas iteraciones.

Comment: Lo tienes casi todo resuelto. ¿Has intentado hacer la función con el acumulador? Si no te sale, te puedo dar una ayuda.

Comment: No he conseguido hacerla :(

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo. Empecemos con un poco de teoría. Supongamos que queremos hacer la siguiente función:

```
unfold :: a -> [b]
```

Como sugiere el nombre, `unfold` hace la operación inversa de `fold` y similares:

```
fold :: [a] -> b
```

(Nota: del tipo `fold` serían `sum`, `product`, `head`, `last`,...`foldr`, `foldl`,...)

Podemos implementar `unfold` mediante recursión aplicando iterativamente una función `f` para que vaya dando los elementos en orden:

```
unfold :: a -> [b]
unfold x = y : unfold z
  where (y,z) = f x
```

A esta definición le falta la condición de parada para evitar una *recursión infinita*. Lo que se puede apreciar es que no es nada eficiente: se requiere obtener el resto de la lista antes de poder añadir un elemento, lo que va a necesitar bastante memoria para guardar los resultados intermedios hasta el final de la operación.

Introduzcamos un acumulador:

```
unfold :: a -> [b]
unfold = unfoldAc []

unfoldAc :: [b] -> a -> [b]
unfoldAc xs x | cond x    = xs
              | otherwise = unfoldAc (y:xs) z
  where (y,z) = f x
```

En el primer argumento `xs` de `unfoldAc` va el acumulador. Empieza vacío y se va llenando de los elementos generados. Cuando se cumpla la condición `cond`, se para la recursión y devuelve lo que haya en el acumulador. Lo bueno de esta implementación es que no se requiere guardar ningún resultado intermedio ya que todo se pasa como argumento. Es lo que se conoce como *"optimización **tailrec**"*.

Veamos cómo cambiar tu implementación de `digitosDe` metiendo un acumulador:

```
digitosDe :: Integer -> [Integer]
digitosDe = digitosDe' []
 where
  digitosDeAc xs x | x < 10    = x : xs
                   | otherwise = digitosDeAc (m : xs) d
    where (d, m) = x `divMod` 10
```

Como se ve, se van *acumulando* las cifras que calcula, y en el orden que queremos (primero mete en el acumulador las unidades, luego las decenas, etc, etc).

De todos modos, hay una implementación más directa (aunque menos elegante) usando los métodos de lectura/escritura de haskell:

```
digitosDe :: Integer -> [Integer]
digitosDe x = [ read [c] | c <- show x ]
```

Pero vayamos al caso que nos ocupa, cómo meter el acumulador en la función `esFeliz`:

```
esFeliz :: Integer -> Bool
esFeliz = esFelizAc []
 where
  esFelizAc xs x | x `elem` xs = False
                 | s == 1      = True
                 | otherwise   = esFelizAc (x : xs) s
    where s = sumaCuadradosDigitos x
```

El acumulador lo usamos para ir metiendo aquellos números que ya hemos visto. Si el número a comprobar ya ha sido visto, devuelve `False`(*infeliz*). Si la suma de cuadrados es 1, devuelve `True` (*feliz*). Si ni una ni otra cosa, entonces lo mete en el acumulador y vuelve a empezar, esta vez con la suma de cuadrados.

Una cosa a tener en cuenta es que todos los números del acumulador son números felices o infelices, según sea el final de la secuencia. Si se fuera a usar mucho esta función, se podría crear una lista de números felices y otra de infelices, e ir llenándola con los números que se vayan viendo. O sea, una función con tres acumuladores. Pero lo dejo aquí porque no quiero complicar más la respuesta.